# Layout was broken in codeigniter and some jquery functionalities when changing http to https

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, layout

I am a newbie with regard to https with codeigniter. I had a problem with my layout when I transfer to and https. In http everything works perfectly but when I purchase an ssl and use https in that matter some how it breaks my layout especially the homepage where I put some picture slider and images.

I would greatly appreciate any answers

Comment: View source of the page, search for any **`http`** links, specially in your slideshow images. If there are any, fix them all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it creates some errors. You might wanna hide it in the index.php if there are notices, but you'd rather repair it if that's somethig else. Code for index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be either not matching resources (e.g. if `http` and `https` directives aren't pointing to the same folder in your web server software configuration) or your pages are requesting non-`https` resources.

For the latter, try using relative paths to resources. e.g.:

```
<script src="scripts/somescript.js"></script>
```

or protocol-agnostic requests:

```
<script src="//example.com/scripts/somescript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Codeigniter, set your base url in the config with https://

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mysite.com/';
```

Then when specifying urls to pages, images, etc within your domain, use the [URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) functions to automatically format your urls.

You want to avoid writing urls like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mysite.com/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="https://mysite.com/index.php/about">About Us</a>
```

And instead generate your urls like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>">About Us</a>
```

This way when you change anything like protocol, domain, etc you don't have to go through your application and update every single url by hand. The helper functions will take care of it.

Comment: Hi Samutz,
I tried this one but for some reason, my layout are not still the same as what I am expecting to show just like what I have in http.